# How can I get iPhone Mail to accept meeting invitations attached as .ics files?

Tags: iphone, gmail, imap, google-calendar

I love my iPhone and it changed the way I deal with email. However there is an annoyance: It seems that the iPhone mail app cannot deal with meeting invitations in .ics format (e.g. sent by Lotus Notes).

I use Gmail via IMAP. When I go to Gmail via PC/Browser it displays the meeting and I can accept the invitation. The Gmail iPhone page also displays it opposed to the iPhone mail client but I cannot accept it.

Is there any iPhone app / hack / workaround so I can accept invitations right inside iPhone mail or iPhone calendar (my Google calendar & contacts get pushed via Google Mobile / ActiveSync)?

Answer (score 1):

When I receive an invitation to my Gmail account, it auto populates in my Google Calendar with a question mark beside it.

Unfortunately you can't accept - however it will now show in your calendar.

If the invite is sent from gmail, there is a link to select if you want to accept the invite.

Not exactly the full answer you're looking for but, hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The iPhones mail app works fine for me or the google calendar in safari. It asks if you want to accept it and simply click yes.